# sticky footer does not stay down when window is resized smaller and than scrolled

Tags: html, css

I'm using a sticky footer that will not stay down if i resize the window smaller and then scroll up.  Also the image for my main wrapper is not scaling down proplery if i resize the window.

working url: http://www.nvcc.edu/home/ssuh/footer/index2.html 
screenshot of problem - http://www.nvcc.edu/home/ssuh/footer/help.html

is there way to keep the footer on the bototm of the page until it hits my content?

html:

```
  <body class="yui-skin-sam  splash_asp">
  <div id="parature_wrapper">  # this has a background image which does not 
  scale right
      <div id="parature_content"></div>  #this has a backgorund image which works.
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
```

css:

```
*, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font: 62.5% Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
 height: 100%;
 }
html {
 height: 100%;  
}

 #parature_wrapper {  /*  wrap all of the content */
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
background: url(topheader.png) no-repeat top left ;
height: auto; 
min-height: 100%;
margin-bottom: -30px}


    #parature_content {     /* Main Page Content goes here. Left KB nav is included. */
 position: absolute;
 top: 166px;
 right: 20px;
 width: 630px;
 background:url(content-bg.png) repeat;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 /*height: 5000px; */
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding: 20px;
```

}

```
  #footer {

clear:both;
margin: 0 auto;
background: url(footer-bg.png) no-repeat    ;
width: 918px;
bottom: 0;
position: relative;
height:28px;

border-top: solid 1px #a49a8b; 
border-left: solid 1px #a49a8b;
border-right: solid 1px #a49a8b;
}
```

Comment: if i resize my windows to 1024 x 768, the background image for my wrapper only covers the screen. I need it to scale all the way with it's child div "parature_content." which as a position absolute. Is sthere a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You could see/use Ryan Fait's sticky footer:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

```
#footer's height:         30px
#parature_content's top: 165px
```

Maybe you should set #parachute_content > .push's height to (30+165)px to adapt to the relative positioning of the content area.

Comment: yea i looked at that earlier. i don't think the wrapper accomodoates absolute positioning child divs.

Comment: i just made some edits using ryan's sticky. changed my div to relative but it's still a huge margins... http://www.nvcc.edu/home/ssuh/footer3/index4.html

Comment: any idea where the scrollbar is being generarted from?

Comment: I don't know, but I don't see it anymore, maybe you fixed it since.

Comment: yea, i had a border 1px that was messing with the footer. got it fixed. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position:fixed` for your footer.

Here's a good resource for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position